# Significant C++ code execution slowdown

Tags: c++, performance

So I have to solve one USACO problem involving computing all the primes <= 100M and printing these of them which are palindromes while the restrictions are 16MB memory and 1 sec executions time. So I had to make a lot of optimisations.
Please take a look at the following block of code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < all.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(all[i] < a) continue;
        else if(all[i] > b) break;
        if(isPrime(all[i]))
        {
            char buffer[50];
            //toString(all[i], buffer);
            int c = all[i];
            log10(2);
            buffer[3] = 2;
            //buffer[(int)log10(all[i])+1] = '\n';
            //buffer[(int)log10(all[i])+2] = '\0';
            //fputs(buffer, pFile);
        }
    }
```

Now, it executes in the satisfying 0.5 sec range, but when I change `log10(2)` to `log10(all[i])` it skyrockets nearly to 2 seconds! For no apparent reason. I'm assigning all[i] to the variable c and it doesn't slow down the execution at all, but when I pass all[i] as parameter, it makes the code 4 times slower! Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Whole code:

```
/*
ID: xxxxxxxx
PROG: pprime
LANG: C++11
*/
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

typedef struct number Number;
ifstream fin("pprime.in");
ofstream fout("pprime.out");
int MAXN = 100000000;
unsigned short bits[2000000] = {};
vector<int> primes;
vector<int> all;
int a, b;
short getBit(int atPos)
{
    int whichNumber = (atPos-1) / 16;
    int atWhichPosInTheNumber = (atPos-1) % 16;
    return ((bits[whichNumber] & (1 << atWhichPosInTheNumber)) >> atWhichPosInTheNumber);
}

void setBit(int atPos)
{
    int whichNumber = (atPos-1) / 16;
    int atWhichPosInTheNumber = (atPos-1) % 16;
    int old = bits[whichNumber];
    bits[whichNumber] = bits[whichNumber] | (1 << atWhichPosInTheNumber);
}

void calcSieve()
{
    for(int i = 2; i < MAXN; ++i)
    {
        if(getBit(i) == 0)
        {
            for(int j = 2*i; j <= (MAXN); j += i)
            {
                setBit(j);
            }
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}
int toInt(list<short> integer)
{
    int number = 0;
    while(!integer.empty())
    {
        int current = integer.front();
        integer.pop_front();
        number = number * 10 + current;
    }
    return number;
}
void toString(int number, char buffer[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(number != 0)
    {
        buffer[i] = number % 10 + '0';
        number /= 10;
    }
}
void DFS(list<short> integer, int N, int atLeast)
{
    if(integer.size() > N)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(!(integer.size() > 0 && (integer.front() == 0 || integer.back() % 2 == 0)) && atLeast <= integer.size())
    {
        int toI = toInt(integer);
        if(toI <= b) all.push_back(toInt(integer));
    }

    for(short i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
        integer.push_back(i);
        integer.push_front(i);
        DFS(integer, N, atLeast);
        integer.pop_back();
        integer.pop_front();
    }
}
bool isPrime(int number)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < primes.size() && number > primes[i]; ++i)
    {
        if(number % primes[i] == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    int t = clock();
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    fin >> a >> b;
    MAXN = min(MAXN, b);
    int N = (int)log10(b) + 1;
    int atLeast = (int)log10(a) + 1;
    for(short i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
        list<short> current;
        current.push_back(i);
        DFS(current, N, atLeast);
    }
    list<short> empty;
    DFS(empty, N, atLeast);
    sort(all.begin(), all.end());
    //calcSieve
    calcSieve();
    //


    string output = "";
    int ends =  clock() - t;
    cout<<"Exexution time: "<<((float)ends)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<" seconds";
    cout<<"\nsize: "<<all.size()<<endl;
    FILE* pFile;
    pFile = fopen("pprime.out", "w");


    for(int i = 0; i < all.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(all[i] < a) continue;
        else if(all[i] > b) break;
        if(isPrime(all[i]))
        {
            char buffer[50];
            //toString(all[i], buffer);
            int c = all[i];
            log10(c);
            buffer[3] = 2;
            //buffer[(int)log10(all[i])+1] = '\n';
            //buffer[(int)log10(all[i])+2] = '\0';
            //fputs(buffer, pFile);
        }
    }

    ends =  clock() - t;
    cout<<"\nExexution time: "<<((float)ends)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<" seconds";
    ends =  clock() - t;
    cout<<"\nExexution time: "<<((float)ends)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<" seconds";
    fclose(pFile);
    //fout<<output;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: call to `log10` does nothing, so compiler removes it when you call it for const value and for c, but it cannot remove it for all[i]

Comment: Why have you got that line at all? - it returns a value which you are then discarding.

If you are trying to find the number of digits in 'c' then it would probably be much quicker to do repeated divide by 1000/100/10/etc, than to use log10

Comment: I'm using it just for testing. Now when I change log10(2) with for example int d = log10(2), the code still executes for 0.5 seconds, but when I chage it to int d = log10(all[i]) it slows to 1.7 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've done this backwards.  It seems odd to generate all the possible palindromes (if that's what `DFS` actually does...  that function confuses me) and then check which of them are prime.  Especially since you have to generate the primes anyway.

The other thing is that you are doing a linear search in `isPrime`, which is not taking advantage of the fact that the array is sorted.  Use a binary search instead.

And also, using `list` instead of `vector` for your `DFS` function will hurt your runtime.  Try using a `deque`.

Now, all that said, I think that you should do this the other way around.  There are a huge number of palindromes that won't be prime.  What's the point in generating them?  A simple stack is all you need to check if a number is a palindrome.  Like this:

```
bool IsPalindrome( unsigned int val )
{
    int digits[10];
    int multiplier = 1;
    int *d = digits;

    // Add half of number's digits to a stack
    while( multiplier < val ) {
        *d++ = val % 10;
        val /= 10;
        multiplier *= 10;
    }

    // Adjust for odd-length palindrome
    if( val * 10 < multiplier ) --d;

    // Check remaining digits
    while( val != 0 ) {
        if(*(--d) != val % 10) return false;
        val /= 10;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This avoids the need to call `log10` at all, as well as eliminates all that palindrome generation.  The sieve is pretty fast, and after that you'll only have a few thousand primes to test, most of which will not be palindromes.

Now your whole program becomes something like this:

```
calcSieve();
for( vector<int>::iterator it = primes.begin(); it != primes.end(); it++ ) {
    if( IsPalindrome(*it) ) cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

One other thing to point out.  Two things actually:

```
int MAXN = 100000000;
unsigned short bits[2000000] = {};
```

1. `bits` is too short to represent 100 million flags.
2. `bits` is uninitialised.

To address both these issues, try:

```
unsigned short bits[1 + MAXN / 16] = { 0 };
```

Comment: well, I already managed to make a solution that is really fast. You can see it here https://gist.github.com/AlexanderMitov/9073997. And computing all the primes in the range [1, 100M] proved to be not efficient enough, since I have a 1 sec time limit. And btw, the palindromes aren't that much, ~12K for [1; 100M] and therefore much better to generate a palindrome and check if it is prime than the other way around. And Why do you say I should use Binary search? I'm  not searching for a specific value, in order the algorithm to be correct, I must iterate over all the primes.

Comment: @user1113314 But you are generating all the primes anyway with the sieve.  So your comment about saving time by "only checking if palindromes are prime" is false.  I suggested binary search because your `isPrime` function is doing a linear search in an ordered array.  I'm not sure if you understood my answer particularly well.  I assumed that the code you posted was the code you said was running almost fast enough.  But the solution in your comment is completely different from this solution.

Comment: Ah, yes, now I understand. Since I'm using the sieve, all the palindromes which are prime are 0's there, too. And when I push these primes they contain the palindromes. So my isPrime function just needs to make a Binary search and check if the palindrome is in the vector. But actually it could be done in O(1) time if for a given palinfrome N, I just make a check if(getBit(N) == 0) then it is prime. Thanks for the clarification.